# Combinatorial proof of invertibility of a symmetric matrix associated to the ring of matrices over a finite field

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $F$ be a finite field of $q$ elements with characteristic $p$.  Let $M_n(F)$ be the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$.  We define a $q^{n^2}\times q^{n^2}$ symmetric matrix $L$ over the natural numbers as follows.  Let us index rows and columns by matrices in $M_n(F)$.  Then $$L_{A,B} = q^{n\cdot \dim \mathrm{Fix}(AB)}.$$  Here $\mathrm{Fix}(X)$ is the set of fixed vectors of the matrix $X$, that is, the eigenspace of $1$.  Note that $L_{A,B}$ can alternately be described as the number of matrices $C$ with $ABC=C$, as is easily checked.

**Question.** Find a combinatorial proof that $L$ is invertible over $\mathbb Q$<strike>, or even better over any field of characteristic different than $p$, or even better over $\mathbb Z[1/p]$.</strike>

**Motivation.**

It follows by a result of Putcha and Okninski proving the semisimplicity of $\mathbb QM_n(F)$ that $L$ is invertible over $\mathbb Q$.  <strike>and I believe it follows by a result of Kovacs that $L$ is invertible over any field of characteristic different than $p$ since Kovacs proved that $M_n(F)$ has a strongly symmetric algebra over such fields.  In fact, I believe it is invertible over $\mathbb Z[1/p]$.</strike>   The matrix $L$ is the matrix of the trace form on the monoid algebra of $M_n(F)$.

The results of Putcha and Okninski <strike>and Kovacs</strike> go through the representation theory of the multiplicative monoid $M_n(F)$ and are not so trivial.  A combinatorial proof of the invertibility of $L$ would give a nice new proof of their results.

**Update.** my original hope to invert over fields of characteristic different than $p$ was silly because the trace form on general linear groups vanishes if the characteristic divides the order so Kovacs doesn't help.  I guess if the characteristic is bigger than $q^n\times q^n$ it should be invertible.

Comment: Can the $q$ in the matrix be replaced by a variable?

Comment: Is there a $q=1$ version of this result, considering all maps $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: @SamHopkins, the monoid of all self maps does not have a semisimple algebra.  But if it's probably not the right q=1 analogue.  The Renner monoid for M_n is the monoid of partial permutation matrices or Rook monoid and this has a semisimple algebra in good characteristic

Comment: @Darijgrinberg good question.

Comment: Let us consider $n=1$. Then the matrix in question is a $q\times q$-matrix with rows and columns indexed by elements of $F$, for which $a_{0,x}=a_{x,0}=1$ for all $x$, and for $x,y\ne0$, $a_{x,y}=q$ for $xy=1$ and $a_{x,y}=1$ otherwise. The determinant of this matrix is easy to compute if you subtract row $0$ from all other rows: the answer is $(q-1)^{q-1}$ times the sign of the permutation of $F^{\times}$ that sends any $x$ to $x^{-1}$. Thus for $n=1$ your expectation about invertibility over a field of characteristic different from $p$, or $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ is certainly excessive.

Comment: P.S. Of course one may imagine that something magical happens for $n>1$ that $n=1$ does not detect, but I think that it is unlikely in this case.

Comment: @VladimirDostenko you are right of course. I would have said the characteristic is larger than the size of the monoid. If the characteristic divides the size of the general linear group its trace form vanishes